# i386 deb package for amd64 machines

Tags: 64-bit, deb, multiarch, 32-bit

I am building an application and I want to build a DEB package, but I have a problem...

I want that the DEB package can be installed both 32 bits machines and 64 bits machines.
Then I build a 32 bits package to support both architectures, but I have problems with the dependencies, when a 32 bits system installs the package, works good, but when a 64 bits system installs the package, the dependencies (shared libraries) to be installed should be the 32 bits ones (available on 64 bits repos.)

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: This question is pretty hard to answer without some more detail on what exactly you're trying to do. (Which dependencies, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

A quick answer is given here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/32bit_and_64bit#How_to_Make_32-bit_Applications_Work_on_a_64-bit_Operating_System

Installing `ia32-libs` is surely the fastest solution, however it may not be enough, depending on the situation.

Comment: The problem is that I want to facilitate the installation to user and I don't know if install ia32-libs manually is an easy solution to the user...

Comment: If you are distributing an Ubuntu package, then you can add a `Depends: ia32-libs`. Generally, when using a 32-bit application inside a 64-bit environment, you will always need to install/setup something on the environment to make your application work. Otherwise the only solution is to distribute 64-bits applications.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @maggotbrain: This question is very old, and the solution proposed here is no longer valid. Nowadays, Ubuntu ships with multiarch enabled by default and `ia32-libs` is no longer the best way to work with 32-bit packages. BTW, the essential part of the wiki page is included (2nd line).

Answer (score 1):

With multiarch, this is easy. Just build a i386 deb. On an amd64 machine (if all the dependencies have been multi-arched in Ubuntu) the 32-bit versions of them will be installed.

Answer (score 0):

In the 64-bit installations, there should be an apt entry for the i386 repo, in which case you use `packagename:i386` for the dependency, instead of `packagename`.  An example of this is wine, where you need 32 and 64-bit libs for running all your windows apps.